# Book introducing covering spaces independent of homotopy

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Can anyone please suggest a book on algebraic topology which deals with covering spaces independent of homotopy, fundamental group, etc?

Comment: Wiki hammering, as it is a book suggestion request.

Answer (score 1):

Topology by Munkres has some material on Covering Spaces. You can check out if it suits your needs. You can also see this:

http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/downloads/111101002/

The part which deals with covering spaces has no reference to homotopy.